# На телефонах отображается только половина фона

Tags: css, background

На пк и планшетах все выглядит отлично, а вот как посмотреть на сайт с телефона, то там не весь блок занимает фоню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body, h1, h2,h3,h4, p,a {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/AvenirNext.woff);
  font-family: "AvenirNext";
  font-weight: lighter;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/Futura.woff2);
  font-family: "Futura";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header {
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ul {
  display: flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.Baikal {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textheader {
  color:white;
  font-size: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 40px;
}


.firstpage {
  background: url(../img/baikal.webp);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}

.about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 90vh;
  align-content: flex-end
}

.about_button {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background:none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  transition: 0.5s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
} 
.about_button:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  outline: none;
}
  
.about_button:active {
  background: white;
  outline: none;
}

.about_button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.about_text {
  color:white;
  font-family:Futura;
  font-size:40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.secondpage {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #bbd6e4;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.card-img-top {
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
}

.card-img-top1 {
  height:400px;
  background: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/ritual-shaman-pillars-on-olkhon-island-picture-id819559780?k=6&m=819559780&s=612x612&w=0&h=oAx_5ZeVP5OEGJy1sheuC8qMd3t-KwyyK8Q8O7V6Gdc=);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card-img-top2 {
  height:400px;
  background: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/mountainous-inlet-landscape-on-a-summer-day-picture-id157770270?k=6&m=157770270&s=612x612&w=0&h=ajozuB3MpXi_WoTU_HMfQ5hSOMO-3k-zOsQ3KQfJXzE=);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card-img-top3 {
  height:400px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614357932292-a38393b966a3?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=675&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card-title {
  font-family: Futura;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.card-text {
  font-family: AvenirNext;
}

.row {
  height: 100vh;
}

/*.thirdpage {
  height: 80vh;
}

.thirdheader {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Futura";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
}*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
.firstpage {
  background: url(../img/BaikalMobile.webp);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.textheader {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right:15px;
}

.Baikal {
  display: block;
  margin-left:6px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.about_button {
  width: 400px;
}


.about_text {
  font-size: 35px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .card-text {
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  .card-title {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .card {
    margin:40px 40px 0 40px;
  }
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
.textheader {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.about_text {
  font-size: 25px;}
.about_button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 340px) {
  .about_button {
    height:60px;
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .about_text {
    font-size:20px;
  }

  .textheader {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BaikalPage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="img" href="assets/img/Favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="firstpage">
        <header class="header">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <p class="textheader Baikal">Байкал</p>
                <ul class="ul">
                    <li class="textheader"><a>Об озере</a></li>
                    <li class="textheader"><a>Турбаза</a></li>
                    <li class="textheader"><a>Туры</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="about">
            <p class="about_text">Первая в мире<br> турбаза на Деревьях.</p>
                        <button class="about_button">Подробнее</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="secondpage">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img-top card-img-top1"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Переплыть байкал</h5>
      <p class="card-text">полностью никому не удавалось. Однако, есть официальные данные о попытке:
7 августа 1988 года, Девушка из США Линн Кокс, за 4 часа и 18 минут, она смогла преодолеть расстояние в 18 километров, в холодной воде.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img-top card-img-top2"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Озеро Байкал</h5>
      <p class="card-text">окутано таинственными аномалиями. Во время полного штиля может появиться водяная воронка.Легенда - под этим озером располагается вход в царство умерших, а воронка является проводником.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img-top card-img-top3"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">В озеро</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Байкал впадает около 336 рек, а берет свой исток только одна — Ангара. Если бы Ангара не вытекала из озера, то Байкал был бы морем.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
   <!-- <div class="thirdpage">
      <p class="thirdheader">
        Наши преимущества
      </p>
    </div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Через @media увеличь высоту. А вообще в таких случаях лучше делать автоматического по высоте родителя с нижним паддингом, и будет тебе счастье адаптивное.

Comment: Если через @media увеличить высоту все криво же будет, ведь на разных устройствах разрешение разное

Comment: `.row {min-height: 100vh;}`

Comment: @HussoProd Ты изначально сделал фиксированную высоту, что сильно нехорошо. Поэтому height: auto с паддингом - универсальный выход))

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли!!!